# Validating country codes

Tags: validation

Our enterprise data systems maintain a list of 2-character country codes that I want to enforce inside Salesforce.  I'm having trouble writing a validation rule that successfully does this.

The rule on Lead.Country is:

```
AND( 
 !ISBLANK(Country), 
 LEN(Country) <> 2, 
 NOT(CONTAINS("00:AD:AE:AF:AG:AI:AL:AM:AN:AO:AQ:AR:AS:AT:AU:AW:AX:AZ:BA:"&
    "BB:BD:BE:BF:BG:BH:BI:BJ:BL:BM:BN:BO:BR:BS:BT:BV:BW:BY:BZ:"&
    "CA:CC:CD:CF:CG:CH:CI:CK:CL:CM:CN:CO:CR:CU:CV:CX:CY:CZ:"&
    "DE:DJ:DK:DM:DO:DZ:EC:EE:EG:EH:ER:ES:ET:FI:FJ:FK:FM:FO:FR:"&
    "GA:GB:GD:GE:GF:GH:GI:GL:GM:GN:GP:GQ:GR:GS:GT:GU:GW:GY:HK:HM:HN:"& 
    "HR:HT:HU:ID:IE:IL:IM:IN:IO:IQ:IR:IS:IT:JE:JM:JO:JP:KE:KG:KH:KI:KM:KN:KP:"& 
    "KR:KW:KY:KZ:LA:LB:LC:LI:LK:LR:LS:LT:LU:LV:LY:MA:MC:MD:ME:MF:MG:MH:MK:ML:"& 
    "MM:MN:MO:MP:MQ:MR:MS:MT:MU:MV:MW:MX:MY:MZ:NA:NC:NE:NF:NG:NI:NL:NO:NP:NR:"& 
    "NU:NZ:OM:PA:PE:PF:PG:PH:PK:PL:PM:PN:PR:PS:PT:PW:PY:QA:RE:RO:RS:RU:RW:SA:"& 
    "SB:SC:SD:SE:SG:SH:SI:SJ:SK:SL:SM:SN:SO:SR:ST:SV:SY:SZ:TC:TD:TF:TG:TH:TJ:"& 
    "TK:TL:TM:TN:TO:TR:TT:TV:TW:TZ:UA:UG:UM:US:UY:UZ:VA:VC:VE:VG:VI:VN:VU:WF:"& 
    "WS:XK:YE:YT:YU:ZA:ZM:ZW", Country)) 
  )
```

Here are some sample results:

- Fails validation

  - "1"
  - "ABC"
- Passes validation

  - "A"
  - "AB"

It seems that since every letter of the alphabet is in the Contains block and single or two-character combination passes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in the AND clause.  I re-examined the Salesforce example for US states and realized I need to OR together the LEN and CONTAINS functions.

```
AND( 
 !ISBLANK(Country), 
 OR(
  LEN(Country) <> 2, 
  NOT(CONTAINS("00:AD:AE:AF:AG:AI:AL:AM:AN:AO:AQ:AR:AS:AT:AU:AW:AX:AZ:BA:"&
    "BB:BD:BE:BF:B <snip>)
    )
 )
```

Comment: I find it more natural to use && for AND and || for OR. I feel it makes it more readable: !ISBLANK(Country) && (LEN(Country) <> 2 || !CONTAINS("00:AD:AE:AF", Country))

Comment: I didn't even realize that was an option!  All of the examples I've ever seen just use AND & OR.  Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it redundant to check `ISBLANK(Country)` and `LEN(Country) <> 2`?  A valid code is one where the length is 2, AND it's contained in the list of valid codes.

Comment: No, because this allows for blank (unknown) data. If it didn't have the IsBlank the field would essentially be required. This way, if the field is not blank, the data must be 2 characters long.

Answer (score 9):

Why not trying using a VLookup. you can store all of your values in an object and then use the `VLOOKUP()` formula to see if it exists in the list. That way you avoid running into the size limit on formula fields and you can more easily maintain the list of valid country codes.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en#VLOOKUP

Comment: I will look into that.

Comment: While this did not directly answer my question, it is definitely a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

This exists in the Formula's help documentation:

```
OR(
LEN(BillingCountry) = 1,
NOT(
CONTAINS(
"AF:AX:AL:DZ:AS:AD:AO:AI:AQ:AG:AR:AM:" &
"AW:AU:AZ:BS:BH:BD:BB:BY:BE:BZ:BJ:BM:BT:BO:" &
"BA:BW:BV:BR:IO:BN:BG:BF:BI:KH:CM:CA:CV:KY:" &
"CF:TD:CL:CN:CX:CC:CO:KM:CG:CD:CK:CR:CI:HR:" &
"CU:CY:CZ:DK:DJ:DM:DO:EC:EG:SV:GQ:ER:EE:ET:FK:" &
"FO:FJ:FI:FR:GF:PF:TF:GA:GM:GE:DE:GH:GI:GR:GL:" &
"GD:GP:GU:GT:GG:GN:GW:GY:HT:HM:VA:HN:HK:HU:" &
"IS:IN:ID:IR:IQ:IE:IM:IL:IT:JM:JP:JE:JO:KZ:KE:KI:" &
"KP:KR:KW:KG:LA:LV:LB:LS:LR:LY:LI:LT:LU:MO:MK:" &
"MG:MW:MY:MV:ML:MT:MH:MQ:MR:MU:YT:MX:FM:MD:MC:" &
"MC:MN:ME:MS:MA:MZ:MM:MA:NR:NP:NL:AN:NC:NZ:NI:" &
"NE:NG:NU:NF:MP:NO:OM:PK:PW:PS:PA:PG:PY:PE:PH:" &
"PN:PL:PT:PR:QA:RE:RO:RU:RW:SH:KN:LC:PM:VC:WS:" &
"SM:ST:SA:SN:RS:SC:SL:SG:SK:SI:SB:SO:ZA:GS:ES:" &
"LK:SD:SR:SJ:SZ:SE:CH:SY:TW:TJ:TZ:TH:TL:TG:TK:" &
"TO:TT:TN:TR:TM:TC:TV:UG:UA:AE:GB:US:UM:UY:UZ:" &
"VU:VE:VN:VG:VI:WF:EH:YE:ZM:ZW",
BillingCountry)))
```